# Amazon DynamoDB iOS file not found

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run the sample project of Amazon DynamoDB.

For some reason it doesn't have a DynamoDB.h file anywhere in the folder and it is trying to include one in the source code, so I get an error saying DynamoDB.h not found

I tried looking for DynamoDB.h on github, but didn't find that too.

Anyone else having this problem?

```
This is the download link I'm using:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples
```

Comment: Have you executed `pod install` for downloaded project? There is a dependency on `pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2'`.

Comment: agree. see the guide here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBSample

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Even after you install the 'AWSiOSSDKv2' by pod, there is still no script named "DynamoDB.h".

The way I fix it is that I find there is a script named "AWSDynamoDB.h" under Pods/AWSDynamoDB folder, which looks like the correct file it want to import.

So I replace all #import "DynamoDB.h" by #import "AWSDynamoDB.h".
It is runnable.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the sample code you also need the SDK

The [SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/)
The [iOS SDK](http://sdk-for-ios.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-ios-sdk.zip)